# Download the HTML table on my desktop area in XML format on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html

I am learning jquery and I am stuck with a functionality. I would like to download this table on my desktop area in XML format on click of a button  using HTML5/javascript/jquery. I don't want to involve any server. Please help with the entire code. Thanks.

```
<script>
var table8_Props = {
col_0: "select",
public_methods: true
};
var tf8 = setFilterGrid("table8", table8_Props);
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/avw8u59z/2/)

Comment: Similar question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343851/convert-html-table-into-xml-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: For downloading the contents of the `xml` variable generated, you could use [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify).

Comment: mk117 - Thanks for the help. With downloadify, can we download it in .xml format? Downloadify provides an option for .txt format.

Comment: Well, read the [**::options::**](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), on the documentation of the main page: checkout `dataType: ‘string’` which I believe stands for the output format of your downloaded file .... In your case you only need to specify the filename with .xml extension which you can [**::test::**](http://www.pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) by changing the filename.txt to filename.xml ... xml is a text based format, so your generated xml will be in text format, outputted as an xml filetype.

Comment: mk117. I am not a coding expert. Can you please post the entire code in a working fiddle as it'll be a great option. I'll be very thankful to you.

Comment: Here's the  ::[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avw8u59z/3/):: ... I couldn't create dynamic xml that should be available on change of select option of names on top row, also there's an error in the generated xml: The first item is blank. I could probably spend more time on this, but I some work to do, so couldn't find any more time right now... might post an update to the jsfiddle later...

Comment: mk117...Believe me, you are really an awesome problem solver....
I can't tell you, that I was struggling with this problem since a long time. Thanks a lot....:-)

Comment: Thanks! And welcome! Glad to know the code was helpful!

Comment: When I click on the download button, it downloads the file in XML format but when I try to open that downloaded XML file in the chrome, it doesn't display that file in XML tree like format whereas when I try to open it in notepad, it shows up in the XML format. Please solve this issue.....rest everything is perfect...I fell short of words to thank you...:-)

Comment: I won't be able to resolve this right now, cause I'm browsing on phone and cannot respond with a solution right now.... So will reply back tomorrow.

Comment: Please solve this asap because its needs immediate attention. I'll be waiting for your response.

Comment: Solved it, item start was missing from the tree ... Here's the ::[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avw8u59z/4/)::

Comment: Check the answer again... I've modified the code to completion! The code now Provides download of the exact html table only! See the jsfiddle at the bottom of my answer...

Comment: Try using this code on your local system. Its working in fiddle but its not working for rows greater than 5 in my system with other browsers esp chrome.

Comment: In case I have any other doubt, I'll get back to you. Thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the script that will output html table into xml.
Script used to download is [ ::: [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) ::: ].

```
    $(document).ready( function() { 

        var table8_Props = {
    col_0: "select",
        public_methods: true
    };
    var tf8 = setFilterGrid("table8", table8_Props);


function xml_generate (){
            var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n';
            xml = xml + '<items>\n';

        $("#table8 tr:gt(1):not(:hidden)").each(function () {

        var cells = $('td', this);
        console.log(cells.text());
        xml += '<item>\n<name>' + cells.eq(0).text() + '</name>\n';
        xml += '<company>' + cells.eq(1).text() + '</company>\n';
        xml += '<country>' + cells.eq(2).text() + '</country>\n';
        xml += "</item>\n";

});
    xml += '</items>';
   return xml;     
   }
    Downloadify.create('downloadify',{
                filename: function(){
                    return 'table_data.xml';
                },
                data: function(){ 
                    return xml_generate();
                },
                onComplete: function(){ alert('Your File Has Been Saved!'); },
                onCancel: function(){ alert('You have cancelled the saving of this file.'); },
                onError: function(){ alert('You must put something in the File Contents or there will be nothing to save!'); },
                transparent: false,
                swf: 'http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/media/downloadify.swf',
                downloadImage: 'http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/images/download.png',
                width: 100,
                height: 30,
                transparent: true,
                append: false
            });

});
```

HTML:
Add this line of code in the html after the table tag ends.

```
<p id="downloadify">
You must have Flash 10 installed to download this file.
</p>
```

Here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/avw8u59z/6/

Comment: As per the Downloadify documentation, the project needs to be hosted on a web-server, for the download to run. So you'll need to host the files on a webserver, or a local webserver. You could use XAMPP or Dropbox for this if you don't want to upload the files for now. Here are the links to [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html), and [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com) ... For xampp, move your project folder to `htdocs` (access via `localhost`), and for dropbox, move to public folder, and access via `right click > copy public link`