# Convert HTML tables to XML

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have an HTML table filled with content and I want to convert it into XML. I cannot use jQuery or ANY libraries. I must use vanilla JavaScript to do this. [Nearly every tutorial I find says how to convert XML to HTML,](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=how%20to%20convert%20html%20tables%20into%20xml) but none say how to convert from XML to HTML without using a verbose [for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343851/convert-html-table-into-xml-using-javascript-or-jquery) or jQuery.

After researching more, I think what I need is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761399(v=vs.85).aspx) method, but I cannot figure out how to use it. It seems to want to take an XML document as an argument, but I want to create a new XML file based on my HTML table.

Is there a way to convert HTML tables into XML without loops or jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: There aren't many things you can do without loops. Converting tabular data is not one of them.

Comment: Exactly what sort of XML document are you talking about? There's not just one clear way to do that; it could mean in infinitude of different output formats.

Comment: show us a minimalistic sample of the input html and the output xml

Comment: I want to build an XML tree based on the HTML table. I have the table rows as a Javascript object and thought there would be a built in way to just convert it to XML. I'll just build it using loops then if there is not an easier way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to convert HTML tables into XML without loops ->
Yes by using recursion, but loops are probably easiers.

About size of the code, manipulating html DOM in plain javascript IS code heavy, that's why libraries like jquery where made.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my solution without XML DOM API.

```js
function export2xml() {
  let data = `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <js-skills-list>
    ${Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"))
      .map(
        skill => `
      <skill>
        <name>${skill.children[0].innerText}</name>
        <author>${skill.children[1].innerText}</author>
        <description>${skill.children[2].innerText}</description>
      </skill>
    `
      )
      .join("")}
    </js-skills-list>
  `;
  const a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
    type: "text/xml"
  }));
  a.setAttribute("download", "data.xml");
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.btn-group {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<h3>JavaScript Skills</h3>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>jQuery</td>
      <td>John Resig</td>
      <td>The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>React</td>
      <td>Jordan Walke</td>
      <td>React makes it painless to create interactive UIs.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vue.js</td>
      <td>Yuxi You</td>
      <td>The Progressive JavaScript Framework.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button onclick="export2xml()">xml</button>
</div>
```